# WinXP auto-rebooting: It is possible to replace or disable by hardware a LAN adapter in a laptop?

Tags: lan, hardware-failure, reboot

Diagnostics:

- I possibly plugged a wire with RJ-45 connector barely wet to my
  Toshiba laptop LAN port. Network worked fine, then I turned off WinXP without
  disconnecting AC and after 4 hours turned on again.
- WinXP auto-reboots in normal mode (disabling auto-reboot shows a blank display)
- In safe mode it works and it says there is a problem with network
  hardware
- RAM memory is all recognized (2GB). I don't know how to test video card memory
- I disable all network adapters from Hardware Devices and tried boot
  again in Normal mode, no changes, still rebooting.
- Then tried boot in safe mode with network functions, WinXP
  auto-reboots again!!

Question:

Now, in case the LAN device is integrated to my laptop motherboard, there is a way to disable completely or replace it? Any other suggestion?

Comment: Check the bios if you can do it the option will be there... as far as an additional network card; you can get a USB one: https://encrypted.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbm=shop&source=hp&q=usb+wired+nic&pbx=1&oq=usb+wired+nic&aq=f&aqi=g-l1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=13439l14775l2l14877l6l6l0l0l0l3l306l1265l0.1.2.2l5l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=48dbb97a72444f62&biw=1680&bih=920

Answer (score 1):

Check your system [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS), usually accessed  by hitting F2 or Del during initial [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) (at power-on); if you can disable it anywhere, that's going to be the place.